# How to stringify js object, so that multiple double quotes are possible when sending it over Socket.io

Tags: javascript, json, parsing, socket.io, stringify

Well, i guess the main problem is defined in the title, but some special info is:
Im trying to emit events to a socket.io api.
For the eventtype part this is working fine, but when using JSON.stringify on the packet body (event data) part (which is supposed to be in this format:
`"{\"msg\":\"test\"}"`), it only returns this invalid String: `"{"msg":"test"}"`.
I also tried to use single quotes instead of double, but the server doesnt accepts them, so i guess it got a custom parser for these strings.

If anyone has an idea on what to do, i would be really pleased to hear your oppinion.

Comment: I am confused on how `JSON.stringify` or any function could return an invalid string. The only way to create an invalid string is to type it directly into the code.

Comment: So you'd need to escape the double quotes with slashes? That would also mean escaping the slashes with double slashes. That could work like this: str.replace('\', '\\').replace('"', '\"')

Comment: well, i mean the second double quote determinates the string, so the part after it is invalid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get your result by *double stringifying*.

```js
const data = {
  msg: 'test'
};

const stringified = JSON.stringify(data);
const doubleStringified = JSON.stringify(stringified);

console.log(doubleStringified);
```